# Как правильно организовать шаблоны сообщений для логгирования на > python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, логирование

Как правильно организовать шаблоны сообщений для логгирования на  > python 3.10 ?

Для примера я хочу логировать все события купли/продажи товара, а также бизнес исключения.

Язык текста сообщения в логах должен быть конфигурируемым (английский или русский и т.д.)

При продаже товара внужно в лог (INFO) выводить какой товар и по какой цене продался.

В случае если не хватило средств в лог (WARRNING) выводить для какого товара, при какой стоимости сколько денег не хватило и сколько было свободных средств..

В случае режима DEBUG - выводить для каждого бизнес события - состояние переменных.

Писать текст сообщений в самом коде - не очень нравится. Код перестает быть читабельным. Хочется использовать какой-то справочник/шаблон сообщений к которому заранее привязаны переменные которые нужно отображать вместе с сообщением.

Comment: Т.е. как организовать такие шаблоны на Pyhon 3.7 и выше вам понятно? Почему именно ограничение не ниже 3.10?

Comment: Предполагаю что новый синтаксис может повлияеть на подход и/или реализацию.

Comment: Из нового синтаксиса со времен 3.7 добавились только оператор "моржик", switch (или как он там называется) и аннотации стандартными типами (вида `list[int]`), и вроде все. Это никак не влияет на реализацию логирования. Есть сторонние библиотеки для логирования, кроме стандартного logging, но ни одна никак не завязана на какой-то новый синтаксис, насколько я знаю.

Comment: У вас есть свой подход по реализации логгирования в коде ?

Comment: Я не очень представляю что там у вас за процессы. Если лень руками писать, делаете логирующие декораторы, которые например логируют что в функцию приходит и выходит, и логируют исключения. Грубо говоря, пишите декоратор, потом навешиваете на все нужные функции.

Comment: а можете поделиться примером ?

Comment: Есть пример с логированием исключений: https://github.com/dfint/changetextpy_script/blob/9c2b6cd9e21928f8389543922dfe157ae32d8a6e/changetext/logging_tools.py#L32 Для обработки параметров - выводите в логгер все что в wrapper пришло (*args и **kwargs вместо одного параметра text как по ссылке)

Comment: Это хороший вариант для обработки технических исключений, а как на счет бизнес исключений ?

Comment: Без понятия, что вы подразумеваете под бизнес исключениями.